# get Variable from running Task and display on View

Tags: c#, string, mvvm, textbox, viewmodel

The code below executes fine when *MyActionFunc* is called but not when the function is in another class.  MessageBox displays the correct string but it is not shown on view. What I am missing?

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyCommand ActionCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ActionCommand = new MyCommand();
        ActionCommand.CanExecuteFunc = obj => true;
       // ActionCommand.ExecuteFunc = MyActionFunc;
        ActionCommand.ExecuteFunc = MyClass.MyActionFunc;
    }
   
    private string myname;
    public string myName
    {
        get => myname;
        set { myname = value;; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void MyActionFunc(object parameter)
    {
        myName = "Fred";
    }
}
class MyClass
{
    public static void MyActionFunc(object parameter)
    {
        ViewModel name = new ViewModel();
        name.myName = "Fred";
        MessageBox.Show(name.myName);
    }
}
```

... and the binding to the Textbox

```
        <TextBox Name="textBox" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=myName,  Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: You would need to pass the actual ViewModel as `parameter` for that to work. Otherwise you are setting the `myName` property of a new viewModel instance, which isn't bound.

Comment: how could this be achieved? I realize that by calling **new** another memory cell on the stack will be allocated. But how can I pass the reference of the original instance to other method?

Comment: On the heap, not stack. On _how to pass_ it ... errr my WPF skills are tooo rusty, I am afraid. I would _guess_ there should be a way to bind it to the parameter via XAML ... but really, it's been ages since I've dealt with that.